# How to renamed Page_load to PageName_load in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
      Instead of page_load i want to write PageName_Load, how can i do
```

Recently this question was asked my the one of the company in interview

REgards
Praveen

Comment: I know this is just an interview question, but something to keep in mind: for the sake of code maintainability, actually doing this would be a bad idea.

Answer (score 5):

Attaching an event handler to it in the constructor:

```
public class MyPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
   public MyPage()
   {
      this.Load += new EventHandler(MyPage_Load);
   }


   void MyPage_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {

   }
}
```

I don't believe that there is any support in changing the default convention; could be wrong.

Comment: Agreed, however I tend to like to make it explicitly known it's an event attachment. (Besides, [MSDN likes doing so, too](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.load.aspx)!)

Answer (score 1):

It was well described long time ago here at StackOverflow: [What calls Page_Load and how does it do it?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1494561/166584)

Answer (score 0):

To supplement Brian and invisible's post, you can also change your web templates to create a page the way you want.

Navigate to your ASP templates directory:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Web\1033

*This may change depending on your environment, but that should get you in the neighborhood).*

Locate and extract `WebForm.zip` <sup>(Always keep a backup!)</sup>. You'll note a few files in this template:

- `Default.aspx`
  ASPX page template
- `Default.aspx.cs`
  Code-Behind template (where you would typically add your own code)
- `Default.aspx.designer.cs`
  IDE-Generated file (which manages the list of controls on the page).
- `WebForm.vstemplate`
  Metadata that describes the template required libraries, etc.

From there, a few edits make it it the default behavior:

1. Edit **Default.aspx** and remove `AutoEventWireup="true"` from the heading.
2. Edit **Default.aspx.cs** and change `Page_Load` to `PageName_Load` (or you could use `Page$classname$_Load` i suppose...)
3. Edit **Default.aspx.designer.cs** and add a constructor that binds `this.Load += new EventHandler(PageName_Load)`

Save all changes, re-compress back to the zip file and make sure it's in your template directory. Now all new pages will use that template.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class BasePage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public BasePage()
    {
        var myPageLoadDelegate = (EventHandler)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(EventHandler), this, this.GetType().BaseType.Name + "_Load", true, false);
        if (myPageLoadDelegate != null)
        {
            this.Load += myPageLoadDelegate;
        }
    }
}

public partial class WebForm1 : BasePage
{
    protected void WebForm1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```